# How to find all synoyms for a french word using NLTK

Tags: nltk, french

I would like to find all synonyms of a french word. I have implemented used this code:

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
syns=[synset.lemma_names('fra') for synset in wordnet.synsets('maison', lang='fra')]
print(syns)

The program outputs contextuel similarity not semantic similarity and also there is no output the conjugated verbs.

Any idea please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

based on [this post](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2167#issuecomment-473812236), I suggest this solution:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
from nltk.wsd import lesk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# ['als', 'arb', 'cat', 'cmn', 'dan', 'eng', 'eus', 'fas',
# 'fin', 'fra', 'fre', 'glg', 'heb', 'ind', 'ita', 'jpn', 'nno',
# 'nob', 'pol', 'por', 'spa', 'tha', 'zsm']
lang='fra'

sent = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize("Je voudrai essayer avec cette phrase")
synsets = [lesk(sent, w, 'n') for w in sent]
print(synsets)

for ws in sent:
    for ss in [n for synset in wn.synsets(ws, lang=lang) for n in synset.lemma_names(lang)]:
        print((ws, ss), '\n')
```

Here is the result:

> [None, None, Synset('trier.n.02'), None, None, Synset('phrase.n.04')]
>
> ('Je', 'je')
>
> ('Je', 'Moi')
>
> ('Je', 'iode')
>
> ('Je', 'je')
>
> ('Je', 'Moi')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'rendre')
>
> ('essayer', 'tenter')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'goût')
>
> ('essayer', 'goûter')
>
> ('essayer', 'priser')
>
> ('essayer', 'tenter')
>
> ('essayer', 'assumer')
>
> ('essayer', 'entreprendre')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'tenter')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'aspirer')
>
> ('essayer', 'chercher')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'solliciter')
>
> ('essayer', 'tendre')
>
> ('essayer', 'trouver')
>
> ('essayer', 'entendre')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'décider')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'juge')
>
> ('essayer', 'juger')
>
> ('essayer', 'tenter')
>
> ('essayer', 'chercher')
>
> ('essayer', 'efforcer')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'tenter')
>
> ('essayer', 'essayer')
>
> ('essayer', 'tester')
>
> ('essayer', 'vérifier')
>
> ('phrase', 'condamner')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'condamnation')
>
> ('phrase', 'conviction')
>
> ('phrase', 'jugement')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'sentence')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'connexion')
>
> ('phrase', 'expression')
>
> ('phrase', 'locution')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'syntagme')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'théorème')
>
> ('phrase', 'locution')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'syntagme')
>
> ('phrase', 'mouvement')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'délai')
>
> ('phrase', 'durée')
>
> ('phrase', 'fois')
>
> ('phrase', 'jugement')
>
> ('phrase', 'longtemps')
>
> ('phrase', 'peine')
>
> ('phrase', 'phrase')
>
> ('phrase', 'temps')